# How to take out a row of a matrix that contains a maximum in each column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a matrix of data with 3 columns : x , y , z : each with lots of rows.

I need to find the row that contains the maximum each time for each column and also the same thing for minimums then write all these rows to a dataframe.

let's say I have :

```
x= [1,2,4,3] , y= [7,8,6,5] , z= [12,10,11,9]
```

to find the corresponding row I did :

```
alldata=[];

alldata.append([x]);

alldata.append([y]);

alldata.append([z]);

for elem in alldata:
    xarr=np.array(elem)
    rowmax=xarr.argmax()
    ind= alldata.index(elem)
    maxcorr.append(alldata[ind][0][rowmax])

for elem in alldata:
    xarr=np.array(elem)
    rowmin=xarr.argmin()
    ind= alldata.index(elem)
    maxcorr.append(alldata[ind][0][rowmin])
```

The problem is when I need to write the corresponding row that will be something like :

xmax,y,z,x2,ymax,z2,x3,y3,zmax,xmin,y4,z4,.....

for writing the corresponding row I tried :

```
x=np.transpose(x);

y=np.transpose(y);

z=np.transpose(z);

mydata=[]
mydata.append(x)
mydata.append(y)
mydata.append(z)

mydata=np.array(mydata)
```

to write on dataframe I have :

```
casename=['Xmax', 'Y', 'Z', ,'Xmin', 'Y', 'Z', 'X', 'Ymax', 'Z', 'X', 'Ymin', 'Z', 'X', 'Y', 'Zmax','X', 'Y', 'Zmin']
mydata=np.array(mydata).reshape(-1, len(casename))
df = pd.DataFrame(mydata, index=Filenames, columns=casename)
```

clearly mydata is the form that I am searching for , that is not formulated in the code and is my question. it gets impossible to take out the corresponding row from  mydata

For example, the output I want according to the example is:

[ 4, 5, 11, 1, 7, 12, 2,8,10, 3,5,9,  1,7,12, 3,5,9]

also one thing : the Filenames should not change, cause I have several files with these X ,Y ,Z data

Comment: I don't get the output format you need. You also speak of a dataframe, is that the output? Perhaps you could give an example of the output too...

Comment: Sure, I changed the example number, since it's a small list, there can be repititioma in output, since the same row could be taken twice since it both contains the min and or max of different variables but I tried to displace the numbers to avoid it amap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am solving this using `pandas` since you tagged the question with the same. Also, I couldn't match the output you have given. I hope it is a typo. But I have gone by the description you have given ie;`xmax,y,z,x2,ymax,z2,x3,y3,zmax,xmin,y4,z4,.....`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x, y, z)), columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
mylist = []
for i in df.columns:
    mylist+=(list(df.loc[df[i].argmax()]))
for i in df.columns:
    mylist+=(list(df.loc[df[i].argmin()]))
Out: [4, 6, 11, 2, 8, 10, 1, 7, 12, 1, 7, 12, 3, 5, 9, 3, 5, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you so much , just to make sure, by x1,x2,y2,z3,... I mean the corresponding x or y or z on the same row where one of the values X or Y or Z are max or min . Is that what is in your case ?

Comment: yes. That's the case I have tried to answer. You can verify that with your input arrays.

Comment: dear Najeem, I guess , I just mistook the order, I had to write . but anyway , did you notice that the x2 is not really the second argument of x and is only the corresponding row when the y  is maximum and so on ?